# Is there a way to transition a div to be visible by making it visible from top and then going down?

Tags: html, css, transition

Is there a way to transition a div to be visible by making it visible from the top and then going down?
Example:

```
#div {
visibility: hidden;
transition: visibility 1s (??);
}

#outerdiv:hover #div{
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will be possible with vanilla html/css. Jquery has a built in function called [slideDown](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) that allows for this behavior. You could implement something similar using vanilla javascript if you're not using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you can´t do fades in and out with the display option, because it doesn´t have a intermediate state. If you want to acheve a opacity fade, you must use the css opacity option, and a trigger for the div to call this changes. The code will look like the following:

CSS:

```
div{
opacity: 0;
transition: 1s;
}

/*in this case I will use hover as the trigger*/
div:hover{
opacity:1;
}
```

On the other hand, if you want the div to do the fade in at the moment that the web loads, you will need to create a function in js, that will be called at the moment that the page loads, using onload="function()".

Comment: Yeah, but im wondering if its possible to not just make all of it slowly fade til opacity 1, but to make it fade from top to bottom if you get what i mean.

Comment: In that case, you could make use of the [animation css tools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp). With those tools, you can place the div in a x position, and then moving it to a y posicion. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kK-cA99SA0&t=1163s) out, it helped me a lot with css animations.